# Magento2: how can we use xsd file in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

what is role of xsd files which are located in etc (eg: etc/abc.xsd) and how can we use these files in Magento2 and also how can we relate it from magento1.*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XSD files used to validate configuration in XML formats. 
See details in [official Magento2 documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/config/config-create.html#config-files-validate)

In Magento 1.x this functionality is not available